# How to get a list of all keys using the restful api?

Tags: etcd

In ETCD, how can I get a list of all keys using the restful api `/v3/kv`? I can get a range of keys using this endpoint `[POST] /v3/range` but the end of the range is not known so I am looking for an API that can list all keys.